# ggmap - missing value

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm getting the following error when using ggmap: `Error in if (is.waive(data) || empty(data)) return(cbind(data, PANEL = integer(0))) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` 
I've been using ggmap for quite some time now, but can't figure out what the problem is - tried running it on different versions of R (3.3.2, 3.3.3), still getting the same problem. Other datasets with the same spatial extent plot ok...

toy dataset

```
sub <- structure(list(Lat = c(49.3292885463864, 49.3316446084215, 
49.3300452342386, 49.3317620975044, 49.3304515659156, 49.3305117886863, 
49.3283736754004, 49.3307167462002, 49.3318995940679, 49.333169419547, 
49.3309562839252, 49.3317698899629, 49.3281374770165, 49.3316554590127, 
49.3326735200194, 49.331519408234, 49.3280156106529, 49.3291709916829, 
49.3328300103323, 49.3306140984074), Lon = c(-117.657207875892, 
-117.672957375133, -117.66331506511, -117.672862630678, -117.66304525751, 
-117.668207331581, -117.655158806988, -117.66229183045, -117.673965605927, 
-117.673707660621, -117.662873110863, -117.673069192809, -117.655568553898, 
-117.674182492008, -117.673907352374, -117.675914855, -117.65485127671, 
-117.657316414995, -117.671748537091, -117.662937333234), z = 
c(9.27369836928302, 2.39183027404169, -1.93395087707449, -3.18890166171755, 
-0.97968656067399, 2.2968631268102, 8.25209737911514, -1.44955530148785, 
-1.16576549902187, 0.341268832113262, -1.15519233610136, 10.2579242298728, 
-4.65813764430002, 0.301315621593428, 5.25169173852741, -5.37463429849591, 
 4.70020657978266, -4.64139357200872, -1.38702225667279, 9.38668592801448)), 
 .Names = c("Lat", "Lon", "z"), row.names = c(266748L, 266749L, 266750L, 
266756L, 266758L, 266760L, 266768L, 266770L, 266771L, 266772L, 266778L, 
266782L, 266783L, 266784L, 266787L, 266791L, 266792L, 266796L, 
266801L, 266802L), class = "data.frame")
```

code

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

prep <- get_googlemap(center = c(-117.660, 49.329), zoom = 14, 
maptype = 'satellite', scale = 2)

map <- ggmap(prep, size = c(100, 200), 
    extent='device', darken = 0, legend = "bottom",
    base_layer = ggplot(data = sub, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat))) 

map
map + geom_point(data = sub, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, colour = z), size = 1)
```

EDIT

I need to use facets, which is why the `base_layer` call is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the `base_layer` bit?

This works fine for me:

```
map <- ggmap(prep, size = c(100, 200), 
             extent='device', darken = 0, legend = "bottom")
map + geom_point(data = sub, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, colour = z), size = 1)
```

---

**Update:**

Works with `facet_wrap`, too!

```
sub$facet <- sample(x = 1:4, size = nrow(sub), replace = TRUE)

map2 <- ggmap(ggmap = get_googlemap(maptype = 'satellite',
                                    center = c(-117.660, 49.329), 
                                    zoom = 14)) +
  geom_point(data = sub, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, colour = z), size = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ facet, nrow = 2)
```

Comment: Will need to use facets,  which require the base_layer, as far as I understand...

Comment: I wonder when that changed. The ggmap help sure makes it sound like you need the base_layer for faceting! It's only Tuesday, and I already learned something ;-) http://127.0.0.1:22682/library/ggmap/html/ggmap.html